# How to calculate the slope of a square in three dimensions

Tags: angle, slope

Suppose I have a square which has the following coordinates at its corners:

```
A (0, 0, 10); B (0, 10, 7); C (10, 10, 8); D (10, 0, 5)
```

Drawn with [GeoGebra](https://www.geogebra.org/), it looks something like this:

[image: Square]

Is it possible to calculate a "total" slope of the square in reference to the x-y plane, e. g. it has a slope of 30° and if yes, how to do it?

(Some ressources would also be greatly appreciated)

Comment: If someone gives you $3$ points in space, then there is only one plane which passes through those points. However, you have $4$ points. When you have $4$ points, the points do not usually all lie in the same plane. As such, it is difficult to say what the slope is.

Comment: What is the difference between "*total slope*" and "*slope*?" Can you provide a formal definition of "*total slope*"?

Comment: @SamuelMuldoon As you mentioned, it is not a plane and hence it is not possible to calculate a slope. I just split it up into two triangles and calculate the slopes of those.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This isn't a square because,
for example,
the distance AB is not the same as BC.

Also, the points are not in n the same plane,
so talking about the slope is not meaningful.

Comment: As mentioned in the comments above, calculating the slope of the figure drawn above is not possible. An alternative is to create triangles, where the slope can be calculated as mentioned [here](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/105850/calculate-the-slope-of-a-3d-triangle)